# Solving integral 1/(1+x^2)

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that
$\int_{- \infty }^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx=[\tan^{-1} x]_{- \infty }^{\infty} = \frac{\pi}{2}-(-\frac{\pi}{2})=\pi$?

I'm integrating after a long period of time of inactivity, and sometimes I have doubts.

Comment: $$\text{Yes!}$$

Comment: Yes, Indeed it is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. If you want to see a way to find the antiderivative without having known in advance, let $x=\tan(\theta), dx = \sec^2(\theta)$. Then the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx = \int \frac{1}{1+\tan^2(\theta)}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta = \int \frac{1}{\sec^2(\theta)}\sec^2(\theta) d\theta$$
$$= \int d\theta =\theta+C = \tan^{-1}(x)+C$$